# Hide the navigation bar when the menu has been clicked?

Tags: android, android-menu, android-navigation-bar

I'm building an Android native app with Android Studio & I got a problem with the navigation bar...

I succeeded to hide the navigation bar on the main screen with this code :

```java
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION 
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}
```

But it reappears when I click on the menu and this is annoying because I don't know how to hide it...

[image: Naviagtion bar reappear]

If someone could help me, it will be awesome !

Comment: You want to hide menus, for example, when you click a button and then to show it again after some process?

Comment: No, I want hide the naviagtion bar all the time ! The main problem is that when I click on the menu, the navigation bar appears as on the screenshot...

Answer (score 0):

Remove toolbar from your xml and use a style

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I don't well understand your answer...
In which xml should I remove the toolbar ?
And what remove ?

Comment: xml of your corresponding screen you mentioned above.